# Could not retrieve data from URL. facebook debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook opengraph debuger said: Could not retrieve data from URL.
for this address :
http://reshet.tv/shows/amamyot/video/.aspx?bo=12568

why ? 
if i try to go to the site from direct ip of the server, it is working well..

Maybe because we use load balancer ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparantly the scraper sees something which he can't use. Have a look at the scraper output via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Freshet.tv%2Fshows%2Famamyot%2Fvideo%2F.aspx%3Fbo%3D12568

Comment: in the sample in the link you attached, it seems OK for now. This is OK right now, Once it works and sometimes not thanks you.   in an hour ago it wasn't ok.